# Unable to send email after tests run using Maven Postman plugin

Tags: java, maven, selenium, maven-plugin, surefire

I've been trying all morning but have not had any success sending emails after running my Selenium test suite from the command line using Maven. Here is how we run the suite from the command line.

```
mvn surefire:test
```

This is using the Surefire plugin to run a suite of TestNG/Selenium tests. This works great and we want to keep using it. What I need is a way to email the results after each running of the suite. I came across the [Postman](http://doc.fortysix.ch/maven/maven-postman-plugin/index.html) plugin and it looks perfect. Only problem is I can't get it to work at all. Here is my maven .pom file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mysite.carelogic.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>automation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>carelogic-automation</name>
<description>automation tests for carelogic webapp</description>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.37.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>20030203.000129</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>send surefire notification</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>send-mail</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <from>conner@mysite.com</from>
                            <subject>Automation Test Results</subject>
                            <mailhost>relay.mysite.com</mailhost>
                            <htmlMessageFile>target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html</htmlMessageFile>
                            <receivers>
                                <receiver>conner@mysite.com</receiver>
                                <receiver>conner@gmail.com</receiver>
                            </receivers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showSuccess>true</showSuccess>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I've confirmed with our techops that our mail server is relay.mysite.com and it is free to use on port 25. No user or password is necessary. When I run the maven command my tests run and I can see what passed and failed but I see no notification that maven tried to send any emails. So I have no idea where to start debugging to see what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT
Here is the command line output I get when running the above mvn command. As you can see there is no mention of the postman plugin or emails in general.

```
Results :

Failed tests: 
  Coleman.shouldBeAbleToVerifyClientCaseLoad:84->BaseSmokeTest.shouldBeAbleToVerifyClientCaseLoad:294 » NoSuchElement

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.727s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 03 11:44:49 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/141M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project automation: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Projects\automation\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project automation: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Projects\automation\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Projects\automation\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:852)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:720)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Maven execution is never reaching the mail sending plugin because there are test failures. Add these lines in maven-surefire-plugin's configuration section :

```
                <testErrorIgnore>true</testErrorIgnore>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
```

That should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help!

Add the failsafe plugin to you pom.xml
And that would help maven to generate a report even if there are test failures. Then the Postman plugin will come into action.
Also, I am using the below path and tag for email attachments and it works fine for me.

```xml
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <!-- Report directory Path -->
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/site/serenity</directory>
        <includes>
            <!-- Report file name -->
            <include>**/serenity-summary.html</include>
        </includes>
        <!-- Use Regular Expressions like **/*.html if you want all the html files to send-->
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

My failsafe plugin configuration is:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
```

All in all, what is happening here is that failsafe will allow maven to execute completely even when there are test failures and then fileset seems to be the correct tag to send an attachment.