# How to configure maven postman plugin to send email only if test fails

Tags: java, maven, email, plugins, postman

I have configured maven postman plugin in my pom.xml & could receive email always either tests pass or fail. I want to receive email only if test failed. Tried many ways but no success yet. look at the groovyCondition below. Can someone pls help?

tried this too but not working - http://doc.fortysix.ch/maven/maven-postman-plugin/surefire-mail.html

Here is my pom.xml snippet -

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skip>false</skip>
            <from>akash1234</from>
            <failonerror>true</failonerror>
            <mailhost>host1234</mailhost>
            <mailport>007</mailport>
            <receivers>
                <receiver>akashxxxxxx</receiver>
            </receivers>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>send surefire notification</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>surefire-mail</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <subject>Test Surefire</subject>
                <groovyCondition><![CDATA[failures > 0]]></groovyCondition>
                <receivers>
                   <receiver>akashxxxxxx</receiver>
                </receivers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
</build>        

<reporting>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
      </plugin> 
<plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: have you written any testcases?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in maven-surefire-plugin's configuration section:

```
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
```

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533524/unable-to-send-email-after-tests-run-using-maven-postman-plugin/25962769#25962769?newreg=d8c4606beb5d4131bfe75eac2732a8ab)